# Can you create a class via an object reference?

Tags: coffeescript

Is something like this possible?

```
var obj = {test: hi}

class TestClass 
  obj
```

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is create a mixin that I can add to the class

Answer (score 0):

They way you are trying to do it, is not supported in coffeescript. The usual approach for dynamic extension of objects is to extend their prototype. The coffeescript class syntax is actually nothing but sugar for adding methods to the prototype (instance methods) or the class function (static methods).

Have a look at [coffeescript mixin recipe](https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/classes_and_objects/mixins). There are also some libraries available that offer mechanisms for mixins.